# Missing Microsoft.SharePoint.dll in asp.net web application

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a asp.net Web Application that can access SharePoint sites. I have referred the documentation of [SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite)

When I try to instantiate SPSite object it says;

```
The Type or namespace does'nt exist.
```

Then I tried to add reference of the `Microsoft.ShairPoint.dll` by **Solution  Explorer -> Add References** option,  but could not found any Microsoft.ShairPoint.dll.

There is `Microsolft.ShairPoint.client/ClientProfile` available, but not the desired one i.e. `Microsoft.ShairPoint.dll`.

**How to resolve this problem?**

Comment: which .Net framework you use?

Comment: I am using 4.5 framework

Comment: Simple Man have you found no answer

Comment: Have you installed SharePoint? Which version?

Comment: Yes i install ShairPoint 2013

Comment: This should be the path : C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

Comment: Hi Inside Microsoft Shared there is no folder exist Web Server

Comment: Hi Inside Microsoft Shared/Web Server Extensions/15 or 16 / ISAPI  inside these folder's Microsoft.ShairPoint.client.dll or many more files same like that exist but no one file Microsolft.ShairPoint.dll exist What Should I do! Please help

Comment: I think in order to get this dll you have to install Windows SharePoint Service which can be install on server only. In your case if you are running client os like windows 7, you can get this dll from Office installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

You must right click on your project and then add reference .. 

select `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client`.

Comment: Hey i just discovered that you if u want to use the server side objects i.e. for example SPSite then you must have Sharepoint installed on your server. Unless you install it , you wont find Microsoft.sharepoint.dll, If however you dont have it installed , u can use client object model for sharepoint , provided you have the user credentials , and the user has Sharepoint access rights. If have any doubts,  please ask .

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :right click the project, go to properties --> change the target Framework to 4.0. and then again add references . and build the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use download and use [SharePoint Client Object Model](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786) and connect to a SharePoint site

Refer related discussion [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/afe4d365-1060-45aa-ac17-354878aaa3c7/include-microsoftsharepointdll-into-c-project-net-40-client-profile-or-greater?forum=csharpgeneral)

We can also use [SharePoint Client SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) to connect to SharePoint site